# Typography text is not breaking line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

**This is my chatbox component where I am mapping the chats to the flexbox but the typography element is not breaking the line with multiline message**

```
  import React from "react";
  import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
  import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
  import { useStyles } from "./dashboad";
  import { GlobalContext } from "../context";
  import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
  const Chat = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { chats, activeTopic } = GlobalContext();
    if (activeTopic) {
      return (
        <div className={classes.chat}>
          <div
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              overflowY: "scroll",
              overflowX: "hidden",
              width: "100%",
            }}
          >
            {chats[activeTopic].map((chat, i) => (
              <div className={classes.flex2} key={i}>
                <Chip label={chat.from} className={classes.chip} />
                <Typography component="p">{chat.msg}</Typography>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  };
  export default Chat;
```

**This is my styling for flex2 class**

```
    flex2: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    width: "80%",
    height: "auto",
    "& > *": { marginRight: "5px" },
  },
```

Comment: it would be great if you can share a working sample code similar to the above one along with the problem that you are facing through codesandbox or codepen. It would ease our task of looking into the problem.

Comment: It's working fine on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chat-flexbox-4qciu). Please check if I'm missing any styling you are using.

Comment: try `flex-wrap: wrap` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_flex-wrap&preval=wrap

Comment: also one more thing, here you're using nested CSS selector which doesn't work in inline styles. use class or `makeStyles` for using nested css selectors